# Rails button_to: how to specify the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't understand what's happening here. I want to put a `button_to` in my (haml) view. If I do this:

```
=button_to( "New", {:action => "new"}, {} )
```

the page generated has:

```
<form action="/cached_input_files/new" class="button_to" method="post">
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="New" />
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="..blah.." />
  </div>
</form>
```

which is OK, but I need to address a different controller. But if I try to specify the controller:

```
=button_to( "New", {:action => "new", :controller => "editor"}, {} )
```

I get:

```
<form action="/assets?action=new&controller=editor" class="button_to" method="post">
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="New" />
    ...
```

I expected the `action` to be `"/editor/new"`, and I have no idea why it isn't, nor how to correctly specify the controller I want to route to.

I'm using Rails 3.2.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't want to include the options in their own hash, I think this is confusing the interpreter.

```
=button_to( "New", :action => "new", :controller => "editor")
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Hmm, OK that works. Thanks! I'm confused though, because I thought I was following the documentation which shows `button_to` with three params: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why the documentation for link_to and button_to are different this respect.  Just upvote/accept my answer, please!  Thanks!

Comment: "Attribute 'controller' not allowed on element input at this point" is the HTML5 validation error this will create, as your input will be something like `<input ... controller='editor' ... />` rather than it simply containing `type="submit"` and perhaps Value and Class etc, relying on the path supplied by the parent form tag. The other answer will give `<form action="/editor/new" ><input type="submit" /></form>`

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
=button_to( "New", new_editor_path, :method => :get )
```